# Serialize collection to parse in python

Tags: c#, python, serialization, deserialization

I have a collection of simple elements in C#. Element is like:

```
public class Element
{
    public string AName { get; private set; }

    public string PName { get; private set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

I need to pass this collection as a string to a Python script. And in python for each element I need to call function like Func(AName, PName, Value). I've done this by serializing collection to JSON in C# and in python write code:

```
elements = json.loads(JSON)
for element in elements:
    Func(routeLayer, element['AName'], element['PName'], element['Value'])
```

But now it turns out that I cannot use Python's json module. So I need a new way to pass this collection to script and dont use any additional modules. I am a real noob in Python, so solutions I can imagine are ugly. Can you give me an advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is some character which you can guarantee is not in the strings for `AName`,`PName` and `Value` then you could use that character as a separator.
In C#, you could "serialize" the information by simply joining the three strings with the separator, e.g. `"foo,bar,baz"`.

Then in Python, the information could be deserialized with

```
aName,pName,value = element.split(',')
```

PS. Just out of curiosity, why can't you import modules in the standard library?

Comment: Yeah, my current idea is to use two separators: one inside my class and second to separate collection elements.
This script is a part of a model and in engine, which execute this module is a bug, which don't allow to use module in Python script...

Answer (score 0):

The most common standard, which should be available in Python as well is XML. Did you consider this option?

**UPDATE:**
You can use [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) in C# to serialize as XML. And [here](http://oreilly.com/catalog/pythonxml/chapter/ch01.html) is something, what i've found for Python

Comment: Thanks, but fast look at python guide has shown that for XML some modules must be used as well:

    `import xml.sax`

Dont think, that it will work.